# Surprise result - merging multiple .csv with headers in different order resulted in correct ordering... why?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I'm quite new to Python and programming in general, so I assume this is a matter of simple ignorance. I have a daily data scraper to get stock data that uses scrapy, and as such does not order the columns (ticker, price, volume etc.) similarly from scrape to scrape. When merging the data, I want to have everything line up together into a single file for analysis.

In hunting around on StackExchange, I found enough clues to cobble this code together, believing that it would be only a part of the answer (and that I would have to include an appropriate ordering of each file prior to merging somewhere else in the code). Instead, this block gives me exactly what I needed - when merging the files, they appear in the same order from file to file even though the original .csv columns are in different orders from file to file.

Why does this code assemble the multiple .csv files according to their headers and not just as-is (think generic copy/paste appending)? I am happily surprised but need to know why it works like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os

path = r'F:\Documents\stock\tests'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*csv"))
merged = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files)
```

Comment: What is `pd` and where did you import it?

Comment: oops, I used the common: import pandas as pd
and import glob, os (edited in original)

Comment: Learn what pd.concat is doing....